# Append one tr to next of current tr

Tags: jquery

I have table with multiple `tr`'s I need to find one `tr` and append one new `tr` next to this current `tr`.

My html looks like

```
<table>
    <tr id='1'></tr>
    <tr id='2'></tr>
    <tr id='3'></tr>
    <tr id='4'></tr>
    <tr id='5'></tr>
    <tr id='6'></tr>
</table>
```

For eg I need to find `tr` with id 2 and append new `tr` next to this `tr`
I need a new `tr` next to `tr` with id 2

How would I do that?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/ - but I suggest you do not have numeric IDs. They are supported in HTML5 but I personally avoid them

Comment: $("#id").after().append("mytr");

But is adding tr inside current tr which is not my requiremnt

Comment: insertafter also not working :(

Comment: try: `$('#2').after('<tr id='24'>Hello</tr>');` Note:' `id` should be unique

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kggkqu1m/2/ here check the fiddle i used .after just like  Pranav did

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)** or **[`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)**

**Example:**

```js
$('<tr/>',{id:'7'}).insertAfter('#2');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id='1'></tr>
    <tr id='2'></tr>
    <tr id='3'></tr>
    <tr id='4'></tr>
    <tr id='5'></tr>
    <tr id='6'></tr>
</table>
```

**or**

```js
$('#2').after($('<tr/>',{id:'7'}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id='1'></tr>
    <tr id='2'></tr>
    <tr id='3'></tr>
    <tr id='4'></tr>
    <tr id='5'></tr>
    <tr id='6'></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @DeepikaThakur : glad to help :)